# Drop down selection on non-model form on form error

Tags: django, django-forms

I've created a non-model form. with a modelchoicefield

```
class BookingFormSetupForm(forms.Form):
    paymentmethod = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PaymentMethod.objects.none(),required=False)
```

I'm running into a problem whereby when a user selects a value on the modelchoicefield and then interacts with the rest of the form, but doesn't enter something correctly on one of the other form fields, an error on the form is thrown on save (which is good), but when the form reloads with the error message being displayed, the value that the user had selected on the modelchoicefield is no longer selected (this is bad). What is selected is the value that was last saved to this field.

Is there a way to have the users previous selection be selected on the reload of the page when an error is displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement under form.is_valid(), you have to initialize the form with the values from the form before reloading the page

```
    paymentmethod = form.cleaned_data['paymentmethod']

    form = BookingFormSetupForm(request.POST or None, user=user, initial={                                                          
                                                                 'paymentmethod': paymentmethod, 
                                                                 })
```